# logstash. convert timestamp to UTC and add to field

Tags: timestamp, utc, logstash

I am shipping combined appache log to logstash. How can I convert event timestamp to UTC and add it to new field?

Comment: You'll need to modify `date` filter to your needs. Shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this. I'm also wanting to do the same thing.. Any heads up ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could use the ruby filter to run whatever code you wanted.

http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/ruby

Ruby's date has a new_offset(0) method to convert to UTC.

Most logstash filter have an add_field option.

Combine those constructs, and you should be all set.